# DropDownButton conditional statement with attributes?

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, drop-down-menu, conditional-statements

I'm having trouble to find out how to check if my **DropDownList** has the attribute **Disabled**

Here is my code (of how I declare my DropDownList):

```
<div class="col-7">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbProperty" runat="server" class="browser-default z-depth-5">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

On page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmbProperty.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

On button click:

```
protected void btnCheckMyProperty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cmbProperty.Enabled == true)
    {
        // I always get a true statement
    }            
}
```

Someone has a clue about it?

Thank you

Comment: What's the issue with setting `cmbProperty.Enabled = false` instead of the `disabled` attribute?

Comment: It dissapears. The DropDownList dissapears (that's probably because of my css settings) if I do `cmbProperty.Enabled = false`, If you pref I can attach a picture of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you commented saying setting `cmbProperty.Enabled = false` messes with your css, you should check the `disabled` attribute in your button click event instead of the `Enabled` property. This is simply:

```
protected void btnCheckMyProperty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cmbProperty.Attributes["disabled"] == "disabled")
    {
        // Your code here...
    }            
}
```

Note: This will NOT error out if the `disabled` attribute is not set. It will return false in that case...

Comment: @ChangeWorld That's one of the beauties of coding... There is endless learning to be done :) Glad I was able to help you out.